# What dose elements of String[] actually store? Reference to a String or String itself?

Tags: java, arrays, string, reference

```
public class ClassNameHere {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] str = new String[2];
      str[0] = "Hello";
      str[1] = "World";
      String test = "God!";
      str[1] = test;
      test = "Guy!";
      System.out.println(str[1]);
   }
}
```

I thought the result should be "Guy!" but actually is "God!". Do the elements in the String[] contain references to Strings? Or just contain the content of Strings directly?

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: No contents of reference types are ever stored "directly" in other objects in the sense that you mean.

Comment: You should look at `str[1]` the same way you look at `test`, in terms of their relationship to the actual objects they are about.

Comment: The "pass by reference" question is not an answer to this.  That is about the semantics of method argument passing.  This is about the semantics of objects and references and ... assignment.

Comment: Thanks, guys! Strings are immutable may be the reason for it! The statment " test = "Guy!" " make the test pointing to a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

First, `String` really falls under category of complex objects in Java, which are passed by reference. However instances of `String` are immutable, and when using concatenation with it (like `test = test + "abc"`) you in fact create a new object, which is no longer linked to the *original* `test` instance.
Second, when assigning a value to a reference of any complex object like this `obj = new Object()` you rewrite the reference, no matter if it's a `String` or any other mutable object, thus `obj` no longer has any connection to the instance it originally held.

If you want to actually get an array of mutable strings, you may want to use `StringBuffer` or any other container that holds a `String` reference / `char` array underneath:

```
StringBuffer[] str = new StringBuffer[2];
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer("test");
str[0] = buff;
buff.append("value");
System.out.println(str[0].toString());
```

Comment: Sorry, I think it is not my point. Because in my opinion,  after I assign test to str[1], both of them should point to the same instance. After I change the content of that instance through reference test, str[i] should equal to the new stuff, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, guy! I finally get your points. Strings are immutable may be the reason for it.

Comment: @Ray you can think of a reference like of a number variable, where number represents address the reference points to. When you create an array of complex object, each element is a reference, i.e. a number variable, which can have whatever value you assign. If you then make a reference `test` and do assignment `str[1] = test` you just copy the number (address) of `test` to `str[1]`. If you later assign new number (address) to `test` it doesn't change whatever `str[1]` assigned to

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I got it， thanks for your answer with patience.